AdMob Initialization Causes Android App to Crash in React Native
I'm having trouble with integrating AdMob in my React Native app. After initializing AdMob, the Android app crashes.
The initialization appears to be successful ( from console log ), but then the app crashes on Android devices.
Code:
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import mobileAds, { BannerAd, BannerAdSize, TestIds, useForeground } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.BANNER : process.env.BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID || '';

function App() {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);
    const bannerRef = useRef<BannerAd>(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        mobileAds().initialize()
            .then(() => {
                setLoaded(true);
                console.log('AdMob initialized successfully');
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error('AdMob initialization error:', error));
    }, []);

    // Only use useForeground for iOS
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            useForeground(() => {
                bannerRef.current?.load();
            });
        }
    }, []);

    if (!loaded) return null;
    if (!adUnitId) {
        console.log('Ad Unit ID is not set');
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <View style={{ height: 50 }}>
            <BannerAd
                ref={bannerRef}
                unitId={adUnitId}
                size={BannerAdSize.BANNER}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

export default App;

I have correctly configured android_app_id in app.json.
I have also set the environment variable BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID correctly.
Logcat shows "AdMob initialized successfully" but then the app crashes.

P.S: Code works fine on iOS. Android is the one crashing.

Please share the stack trace.
